# masonry block or inline-block with span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-masonry

In my webpage masonry's second item itemSelector is not working as required...

I try to use **span** tag to break it in block but not got success. It is showing first 10 pic properly but when use scroll down it load next all pics in one block.

Live example http://www.bhinderblink.com/

My project is fetching pic name from DB with a repeater and jquery. first 10 load directly with asp repeater, next load while use scroll down and pic are loading in Div #imageDiv, jquery .append is fetching data from a xml object.

Script code

```
 function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);

        pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());

        var pic_infoVar = xml.find("pic_info");

        pic_infoVar.each(function () {
            var customer = $(this);
            $("#imageDiv").append("<span class='inline'><img id='theImg' src='/pic/jas/" + customer.find("pic_name").text() + ".jpg" + "'/></span>");

        });
        $("#loader").hide();
    }
```

Body Code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="topBanner">
</div>
<div id="container">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="box">
                <asp:Image ID="zzz" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/pic/jas/" + Eval("pic_name") + ".jpg" %>' />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
        <div class="box">
            <div id="imageDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<img id="loader" alt="" src="loading.gif" style="display: none" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the masonry reload functions, so that it can calculate sizes of the new elements; something like .masonry('reload');

Comment: i try ur suggestion it somehow  working and i put < span > tag on each object of xml on .append , but many pics are overlapping with each other? any suggestion to fix it

Comment: where did you put the reload?

Comment: after .append   

`$("#imageDiv").append("<span class='box'><img id='theImg' src='/pic/jas/" + customer.find("pic_name").text() + ".jpg" + "'/></span>");
                
$('#container').masonry('reload');`